# Is it possible to navigate through routes like in TabBar(with left slide) but without using TabBar but instead using buttons

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to navigate from "Now Showing" to "Coming Soon" with a left swipe on the image, Moreover, I want the Appbar to not to move when I swipe, but I think it is only possible with tab bars and I am not sure, please give some advice if you know how to achieve this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewUcd.jpg)

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can use a PageView for that.

Comment: PageView changes the whole page, I want the Appbar to stay as it is

Comment: PageView doesn't change the whole page if you don't want to.

Comment: Could you show me how to do that

Comment: I've made an example for you. Please check my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I've made an example of what your looking for using a PageView. I've put only text on PageView's children, but you can put there your ListViews or anything you need. When tapping on a button the PageView navigates to the corresponding "page". This can be a starting point for you:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  PageController _pageController = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
  );

  goToPage(num page) {
    _pageController.animateToPage(
      page,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 350),
      curve: Curves.easeIn,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 60.0,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () => goToPage(0),
                          child: Text('Now Showing'),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 4.0,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () => goToPage(1),
                          child: Text('Coming Soon'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 60.0,
                child: PageView(
                  controller: _pageController,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Center(
                      child: Text('Tab 1'),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: Text('Tab 2'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As per **GaboBrandX**, he is correct. But you can also do one thing with the tabs also. The sliding will not work. It is complex, but you can give it a shot.

The picture I will give you, so there would be Tabs and below that there would be a container each container gets replaces by a click.

```
TabController controller;
int activeIndex = 0;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  this.tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
}

//This changes the activeIndex based upon the tabController index
onTabChanged(){
  this.setState((){
    this.activeTabIndex = this.tabController.index;
  });
}

//This will return your container, based upon your tabs selected
Widget getActiveTabView(){
  case 1: {return YourSecondContainer();}
  break;

  default: {return YourFirstContainer();}
}

//Here is your full layout
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      TMTabBar(titles: 'XYZ', controller: this.tabController, onChange: this.onTabChanged),
       this.getActiveTabView(),
    ]
  );
}

//Create a TabBarWidget and do this
class TMTabBar extends StatefulWidget {

  String/List<String> titles;
  TabController controller;
  VoidCallback onChange;

  TMTabBar({@required this.titles, @required this.controller, this.onChange});

  @override
  _TMTabBarState createState() => _TMTabBarState();
}

class _TMTabBarState extends State<TMTabBar> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    //this is for changing the content as per the tabbar
    this.widget.controller.addListener((){
      if(this.widget.controller.indexIsChanging){
        if(this.widget.onChange != null) this.widget.onChange();
      }
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TabBar(tab: YourTabs);
}
```

This basically gives you, what you're hoping for. Hope that helps. Thanks :)